Access an MFE with the hard url without using the shell interface
I am currently developing a micro-front end (MFE) application using Angular 17 with the angular module-federation library version 17.0.8.
I have a shell application that serves as the entry point for my application and two other MFEs, which we'll call MFE1 and MFE2. At the moment, to access these MFEs, I need to navigate through links that load the route of each MFE via the shell, where the links to these MFEs are located. Here is an example code snippet:
{
    path: 'MFE1',
    loadComponent: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        type: 'module',
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js',
        exposedModule: './Route'
      })
      .then(m => m.AppRoutes)
  },


I encounter a problem when I try to access an MFE directly without going through the shell. For instance, when I navigate to the URL localhost:4200/MFE1 (where localhost:4200 is the shell), I get a blank page. Upon inspecting the requests, I notice that there is no request to fetch remoteEntry.js for MFE1, which is the entry point for MFE1.
I've been searching for a solution but haven't found anything. Could you please help me find a solution or an alternative, considering that I will be developing additional MFEs as well?
Thank you!
Nothing now but i search a solution
